# Using SQL Case function to generate a column

Tags: mysql

Lets say for example I have a table that looks like this.

```
-----------------------------
| ID | Name | OID | Changed | 
-----------------------------
| 01 | John |  01 |    N    | 
-----------------------------
| 02 | John |  01 |    Y    | 
-----------------------------
| 03 | Tena |  03 |    N    | 
-----------------------------
```

The table above shows 4 columns ("ID", "Name", "OID" and "Changed").

I want another column to be generated called "Original".
And it is generated with "Y" as a value for that row if "Changed" for a different row is "Y", getting the "OID" value from that row to make the row with that "ID" new column value equal "Y". Something like this

```
----------------------------------------
| ID | Name | OID | Changed | Original |
----------------------------------------
| 01 | John |  01 |    N    |    Y     |
----------------------------------------
| 02 | John |  01 |    Y    |   null   |
----------------------------------------
| 03 | Tena |  03 |    N    |   null   |   
----------------------------------------
```

I have tried some things but couldn't make it work and I think using the Case function might make it work but not too sure how.

Please let me know what you think, thank you.

Comment: You don't need `CASE`, just `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself.

Comment: @Barmar How would I generate the new column?

Comment: Do you need a select query or are you updating the table?

Comment: @varubi I need a select query

Comment: The new column is just the `Changed` column from the joined table, isn't it?

Comment: You said you tried some thing -- please show something you tried, so we can help you understand where you went wrong. We don't just write code for you, we help you fix your failed attempt.

Comment: @Barmar The Changed column is basically saying this person has a different account as it is not the original... That is why I want the original to be found and generated instead of saved in a database.

Comment: And I tried writing something to see if the case function would work... `Case When Changed = "Y" then "Y" where ID = OID` but I don't this is correct at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table with itself:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Changed AS Original
FROM yourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.OID = t2.OID AND t1.ID != t2.ID AND t2.Changed = 'Y'
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN` means we'll get `NULL` for the joined column if it doesn't exist.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/302173/1)

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. it works :)